# How do I see if there is a "word" in a block?

Tags: javascript

there is a block in which I have written things, I have an input and if you hit one (there are 12 in it) you will alert me with something. my code: https://gist.github.com/Xulum12/039c62da55e67d96ca9eb4052f560631

Please help!

(I know I explained a little weirdly but if you look at the code you will understand. And I google translate it)

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please include your code in the question.

Comment: The code is in the link.

Comment: The code is incomplete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use the [Array includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) function. Here's a snippet, based on the Gist you linked, that should work like you want it to.

```js
let kodok = ["test1","test2","djhwajfwa823","84327584hwdaiuodh","h8t4vi32ht8v4o343t","jfiew82t34","8523nov83o5v2n","evunwi543","843u3b4zd","hefdf8834u5tn23","7nb3428ij85g","835v2uiju9o","85v923zwe9o"]

function a() {
  var z = document.getElementById("b").value;
  if (kodok.includes(z)){
    alert("xd");
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <hr>
  <p>code. kis betűvel! (with little letters) ->
    <input id="b"></input>
    <button onclick="a()">click</button>
  </p>
  <hr>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `kodok.includes(z)` isntead of `z == kodok` to achieve your goal.

[Codepen Demo](https://codepen.io/rashedrahat/pen/XWpqEva?editors=1010)

Happy coding :)